# Flutter Doctor found issue Android_Home

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to setup Flutter in windows 10.
I have:

- Android Studio installed
- Visual Studio Code

When I run "andoid doctor" in command prompt is shows no errors:
[image]

But When I try to configure VSCode Editer with steps given in  https://flutter.io/get-started/editor/

It Throws error as show below:
[image]

I tried after setting environment variable as:
ANDROID_HOME = F:\Program Files\Android

Even after setting the above I get the same error.

Comment: I solved it by configuring proper ANDROID_HOME to correct location

Comment: It's perfectly fine to answer your own question - perhaps with details about how you set the variable and how you knew to set it to the other one.

Comment: I have set ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android. AppData is hidden

Comment: have you found the solution, it's still struggling with it?

Comment: I have solved it :)

Comment: @sandeep i have this issue can you help me

Answer (score 13):

My device was not getting  detected by VS Code so , when i searched i found you need to set Android sdk location in Flutter environment for VS code to detect Device so i  went to Flutter sdk folder `C:\Research\flutter` and double clicked on `flutter_console`  which opened a Flutter console and run command 
 `flutter config --android-sdk C:\Users\annur.arya\AppData\android-sdk` and now it works [image]

Answer (score 6):

I just added a solution because the solution is not clear in the comments

You have to use this command to set the ANDROID_HOME to your SDK path

```
export ANDROID_HOME="YOUR_SDK_PATH"
```

According to this discussion, some people had to set both ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to SDK path just like this

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="YOUR_SDK_PATH"
export ANDROID_HOME=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that `ANDROID_HOME` is not set to the same value in both of these cases; try running `echo %ANDROID_HOME` both in the location that works and the terminal where it doesn't. If these values are different, you'll need to figure out why (my guess would be that either you've changed it and not rebooted, or it's being set in a startup script that's only running in one of the contexts).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
I did the following steps :

*/ Open system properties 
*/ Environment variables  
*/ create new system variable 
*/ name : ANDROID_HOME  
*/ value : copy your SDK path 
*/ close your current cmd, and restart it  
*/ run flutter doctor

this should work on windows

Answer (score 0):

You can look in ~/.config/flutter/settings in Linux to manually configure the folder.

Answer (score 0):

GO to Project Structure
set Project SDK to 31 API Or any one 30,29 etc..[image]
and then click Ok