# How do I connect an Android phone to Visual Studio Code?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

VSCode shows 'No Device' in the status bar, while Android Studio has no problems connecting to device over usb, or creating a virtual device.

When I run flutter doctor in VSCode terminal, I get:

[flutter doctor message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNvXs.png)

When I click the 'No Device' (as a shortcut to Flutter: Launch Emulator), I get the error message

> avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK

I've tried:

- updating my PATH variables - I was a bit confused as to which folder I should point to, so I tried every single one I found mention of:

1. C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk;
2. C:\Flutter\flutter\bin;
3. C:\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin;

- updating "dart.flutterSdkPath" in VSCode
- specifying ADB location --> C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe
- uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio
- deleting, downloading, and re-unzipping Android/Sdk/platform-tools

And nothing makes any change.

Comment: "avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK" your problem is with android sdk. try uninstalling and resinstlling it. You should also download the avd in android studio

Comment: May you try Genymotion?

Comment: recheck if usb debugging has been enabled or not?

Comment: @VinamraJaiswal USB debugging has been enabled - no change (VSCode refuses to see any devices regardless if that device is an actual connected device, or an emulated one through Android Studio).

Comment: @Uni I already tried deleting, downloading, and re-unzipping Android/Sdk/platform-tools, shouldn't that take care of it if that was the problem?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115840/flutter-doctor-found-issue-android-home

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the workaround:

Open Android Studio then click on SDK Manager (down-pointing arrow)

This should open a new box with your Android SDK Location at the top. It should look like this:

```
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
```

**Configure the path of android-sdk**

```
flutter config --android-sdk /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
```

**Add android-license to Flutter**

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Then, you can run `flutter doctor` to verify,

Comment: I've done all this and Flutter cli can detect android devices/emulators but not the VS Code extension :( It just keep giving error `avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK`